# Problem with alarm code, need user input and timer in background. Timer works, but doesn't stop program

Tags: python, input, timer, alarm

I'm writing code for an alarm system that runs for a predefined amount of time and allows a user to input code up to three times.  If the code isn't entered correctly within 3 times I have a print statement (will eventually append this with more code) that works as defined, the problem is I need the timeout to execute some code similarly.  As in, if timeout then do this as well, (essentially go to the same line of code the input failure goes to)

```
TIMEOUT = 7 # number of seconds your want for timeout
keycode ="0000";
count = 3

def interrupted(signum, frame):
    "called when read times out"
    print ('Input timeout!!  Contacting Owner!')
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, interrupted)


def input():    
 try:      
  count = 3
  for i in range(3,0,-1):

   userIn= raw_input("Enter the security code to disable the alarm 
system\n");
   if userIn != keycode :
             count = count-1;
             print ("Incorrect Password...Tries Remaining", count);



   else:
             print("Password accepted, security system offline");
             #BRANCHING CODE GOES HERE
             break

  if count == 0:
           print("Contacting Owner!");

           #BRANCHING CODE GOES HERE


 except:
     return


# set alarm
signal.alarm(TIMEOUT)
s = input()
# disable the alarm after success
signal.alarm(0)
```

After timeout, message prints Input timeout!!  Contacting Owner!, but the user can still enter a password.  This is obviously not a very good alarm system!  Ideally I could create an or statement at the "if count == 0 or TIMEOUT: True" kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason adding this little bit of code to the definition section solved the problem

I don't know why, and I don't know how, but getting rid of the 0 on return0 or moving it a space away breaks the codes functionality.  If anyone can explain why that would be amazing.

```
a = 1 ;
def interrupted(signum, frame):

     a = 0;
     "called when read times out"
     print ('Input timeout!!  Contacting Owner!');
     if a == 0:
        return0
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, interrupted)
```